# UNPIVOT Table Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, unpivot

I want to get my table data in rows instead of columns.

Dynamically read the column names too.

Visual example:

```
ColA    ColB    ColC    ColD
1       2       3       4
```

To this:

```
ColA    1
ColB    2
ColC    3
ColD    4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach will "*dynamically*" unpivot your data without having to actually use Dynamic SQL or specify all the field names.

**Full Disclosure:** Gordon's approach is certainly more performant.

**Example**

```
Select C.*
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( values (cast((Select A.* for XML RAW) as xml))) B(XMLData)
 Cross Apply (
                Select Item  = a.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)')
                      ,Value = a.value('.','varchar(max)') 
                 From  B.XMLData.nodes('/row')  as C1(n)
                 Cross Apply C1.n.nodes('./@*') as C2(a)
                 Where a.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)') not in ('Colums','To_Exclude')
             ) C
```

**Returns**

```
Item    Value
ColA    1
ColB    2
ColC    3
ColD    4
```

Answer (score 1):

My preferred method is `apply`:

```
select v.*
from t cross apply
     (values ('colA', t.colA), ('colB', t.colb), ('colC', t.colc), ('colD', t.cold)
     ) v(which, val);
```

Technically, `apply` implements a *lateral join*.  This is very powerful; `unpivot` is just one of many things that it can accomplish.  However, `unpivot` is a good way to get started in learning about `apply`.